# Basis of the space of linear maps between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to know how to define a basis of the space of linear maps : $ \mathcal{L} ( E , F ) $. 
$ E $ and $ F $ are two differents vector spaces.
I'm not looking for how building a basis of its equivalent space $ \mathcal{M}_n ( \mathbb{R} ) $, i know it.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.*

Comment: Sorry, I'm a Morrocan men, I don't speak well english.

Answer (score 7):

If we have a basis for $E$ and a basis for $F$, we can use them to produce a basis for $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ as follows. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be a basis for $E$ and $f_1,\ldots,f_m$ a basis for $F$.

For $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $j\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, define the linear map $\varphi_{ij}:E\to F$ by $\varphi_{ij}\left(a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n\right) = a_if_j$. Then these $mn$ linear maps $\varphi_{ij}$ form a basis for $\mathcal{L}(E,F)$.

Answer (score 0):

Are $E$ and $F$ finite dimensional? If so, [here you go](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis).

The second paragraph [here](http://planetmath.org/DualSpace.html) should be helpful, too.

Comment: Yes, $ E $ and $ F $ are finie dimensional. Thanks :)