# Find a basis for $Hom_K(V, W)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I had this following question on past assignment:

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb K$ of dimension $2$ with basis $e_1$, $e_2$, and $W$ be a vector space of dimension $3$ over $\mathbb K$ with basis $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$. Exhibit a basis of the vector space $Hom_{\mathbb K}(V, W)$ using these bases.

My answer gave a set of six 3x2 matrices where each had a $1$ in some entry and zero's in all the others, with each of the six matrices having a 1 in a different spot. My instructor took off points because I represented the matrices with respect to the standard bases. How can I generally represent the basis of $Hom_{\mathbb K}(V, W)$?

Comment: Suppose V = R^2. My instructor's point was exactly yours (I think), namely that I made a significant assumption in writing the bases the way I did. Could you elaborate on your second point?

Comment: Right, my mistake was doing that. I am not sure how to do the problem without this assumption. That is why I am asking for an example of a basis of Hom_K(V, W).

Comment: While I don't think your professor should have taken points off if you clarified that that matrix is respect to the given bases in $V$ and $W$, if you've understood what a matrix with respect to a basis means, you should be able to describe what each of those matrices means! What would your matrix with $1$ in the top left spot describe as a map on these bases?

Comment: Check here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257975/basis-of-the-space-of-linear-maps-between-vector-spaces Let me know if it's clear..